# want to save file with filename given by user using multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mern, multer

```
    const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Parse URL-encoded bodies for form data
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Gallary");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
  },
});
const Login = mongoose.model("Login", schema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Gallery it is");
});

app.post("/SignUp", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await Login.find(req.body);
    if (result.length == 0) {
      let data = new Login(req.body);
      await data.save();
      res.send({ result: true });
    } else {
      res.send({ result: false });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
});

app.post("/Login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await Login.find(req.body);
    console.log("came");
    if (result.length != 0) {
      res.send({ result: true });
    } else {
      res.send({ result: false });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ result: false });
  }
});

// Define multer storage configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log("place2"+req.body.filename );
    const filename = req.body.filename ? req.body.filename : `default_filename_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
    cb(null, filename);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Define route for image upload
app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log("Uploaded file:", req.file.filename);
  res.json({ filename: req.file.filename });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3001");
});
```

In above code I am trying to save file using multer but it is always saving file  with default name.
in upload route it is printing correct filename but in place2 tag
i am getting undefined when i printing using console.

Why i am getting {} empty object in place2 console.log ,however i am getting correct object or req.body in upload route as sent by the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation, `req.body` may not be properly populated when you use it. Instead of `req.body`, you can try the following -

Use `file.fieldname` instead of `req.body.filename`

Update your code as follows -

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log("place2"+file.fieldname );
    const filename = file.fieldname ? file.fieldname : `default_filename_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
    cb(null, filename);
  },
```

Reference: [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage)